# How can I call four different pages in same screen using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

How can I create an assignment with four screens?

1. Screen with some text
2. Screen with some images image
3. Screen with a video

All the screens will be changed automatically one by one with some time factor
and the time must me configurable i.e you can change time in variable an will be reflected through out the web app.

Comment: Seriously!!! Try it out atleast from your side first. Then if you have any doubt, reach out on SO with code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ng-route.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">

<p><a href="#/">Main</a></p>

<a href="#red">Red</a>
<a href="#green">Green</a>
<a href="#blue">Blue</a>

<div ng-view></div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "main.htm"
    })
    .when("/red", {
        templateUrl : "red.htm"
    })
    .when("/green", {
        templateUrl : "green.htm"
    })
    .when("/blue", {
        templateUrl : "blue.htm"
    });
});
</script>

<p>Click on the links to navigate to "red.htm", "green.htm", "blue.htm", or back to "main.htm"</p>
</body>
</html>
```

You can read further docs on 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Comment: i already tried it ...because i am new here so i didnt posted my code ..now i m going to post...i want change of page on time interval